# Can a one-sample t test suffers from pseudoreplication?

Tags: t-test, experiment-design, bias

I have a simple index of habitat selection. When calculated based on random numbers it results in a normal distribution of mean 0 ( no selection). I'm interested in knowing if a sample of index calculated from real animals also has mean 0. Thus, I though of using a one-sample t-test.

The problem is, I collected samples from 3 localities. I am not especially interested in knowing if localities have an effect, just if all animals as a whole show no selection (mean 0).

However, I suspect that animals from different localities can have different selections. That makes me afraid I might commit pseudo-replication by not considering localities on the analysis. However all mentions to pseudo-replication (or Ommision variable bias) come from ANOVA theory. Is this a potential problem in one-sample tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, you should be concerned whether you sampled from each locality according to the distribution of animals as a whole between the 3 locations. In addition, you should be careful with how the 3 localities were selected and if they are representative of the population of animals as a whole.

Comment: I see. If I understood it correctly, Having differences between locations,  implies that I should sample a sufficient number of locations, to create a representative sample of all behavior of the group as a whole. Thanks.

Comment: Basically, if you want to learn something about the population, your sample needs to be representative of the population. I.e. it should be as if you got a random sample from the population directly, with your sample looking more and more like the population itself as you increase your sample size. Otherwise your sample is not representative of the population you are interested in, and your results will be biased.

Comment: Also, be careful about the size of the effect you are interested in. E.g., what if you find that the mean is different from 0, but it is 0.0000001? With a large enough sample, you are almost guaranteed to find a statistically significant result that your population mean is different from 0, but the actual size of the effect may be so small that in fact your conclusion should be that the mean is not *meaningfully* different from 0.  It depends on what questions you are actually trying to answer with your research- just be sure to keep those in mind and not just blindly apply statistical methods

Comment: Yes, this last topic is something I have been aware for a while. What I could not find is a "correction" for this. I know you can calculate the effect size, but contrary to the p-value, I could not a magical effect size that everyone agrees it is "meaningful"